# Google API refresh token has been expired or revoked

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-ads-api, refresh-token

I am using a Google Ads php library (https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib) to manage **my own** google ads account, following Google's instructions here (https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/first-api-call)

(I've actually been doing this for many years without a problem, but I recently switched over to using a different project in the Google Cloud Platform, so I had to update my credentials and get a new *refresh token*)

To get a new *refresh token*, I ran the php script called `GetRefreshTokenWithoutIniFile.php` (which allows me to grant offline access and retrieve a new refresh token, which I store in a file `auth.ini` for future use).

The *refresh token* last for a few days, before I see this error:

```
{
    "error" : "invalid_grant",
    "error_description" : "Token has been expired or revoked."
}
```

I have been using the above method for years and the refresh token has never expired. However, it now seems to expire every couple of days. I am certainly not 'running out' of refresh tokens (I only request one), and the user is not revoking access (the user is *me*). For that reason, these similar answers don't help me:

- ['Token has been expired or revoked' - Google OAuth2 Refresh token gets expired in few days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66058279/token-has-been-expired-or-revoked-google-oauth2-refresh-token-gets-expired-i)
  suggests an issue with 'security activity', but I see no security issues in my google account.
- [Google token refresh returns "Token has been expired or revoked."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846026/google-token-refresh-returns-token-has-been-expired-or-revoked) and [Since couple of days Refresh token has been automatically expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308211/since-couple-of-days-refresh-token-has-been-automatically-expired) suggest the problem may be too many refresh tokens - however, I only retrieve the token once and re-use the same one (until it expires!)
- According to [Token has expired or revoked - Google Ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66240374/token-has-expired-or-revoked-google-ads?noredirect=1#comment117109587_66240374), a refresh token won't persist unless the app is in 'production' mode. However, I tried that solution and it did not work: the token still expires after a few more days.

Any more ideas?

Comment: @daimto Please vote to reopen, as there is currently no known solution to this problem!

Comment: invalid_grant means that the refresh token you have has expired.   There are a number of causes for that  you have only named one.  Why not read [ask] open a new question show [example] and show the error message.

Comment: Hi @DaImTo, I believe I have quite clearly listed *4* causes (not 1). I explain in my post above that (1) my token has not been revoked by me, (2) no security issues, (3) not requested too many refresh tokens, and (4) I am in production mode. If you know of any others, please do share! You will also see that I have included the error message in my post above, and I have also included the link to the documentation from which my code was created. Anyway, as I state above, the issue is not the code since it was working fine before this. I would appreciate more specific advice!

Comment: This is not a duplicate question and has no answer

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE: This did not solve the problem**

According to [Token has expired or revoked - Google Ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66240374/token-has-expired-or-revoked-google-ads?noredirect=1#comment117109587_66240374), a refresh token won't persist unless the app is in 'production' mode.

The recommended solution is to select "Publish App" from the Google API console. I tried this out, but unfortunately, after a few days of using the refresh token successfully, the refresh token has expired again.

Comment: Perhaps the token expired because it was issued when your app was in development mode. Once you published the app, try deleting your saved OAuth response and recreating it (authorize the app again). The refresh token in this response should not be expiring as long as you keep using it.